# How to move a view (button) programmatically in a constraint layout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to create a simple timetable, (I'm a beginner). I have created a basic layout for the timetable with 7 days and 24 hours, and my idea was to insert buttons programmatically, overlaying the timetable for the correct time and duration by manipulating the position and width of the buttons, so that when clicked they display the task saved in the textview below as such:

[image: Timetable layout]

I know how to create the buttons but after hours of searching for a working method to change their size and location to the desired values with no success I turn here for help.

As a test I made a new empty project with one premade constraint view in the design view and tried to place a single button within it and move it. Here is the code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout01 = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout01); //a constraint layout pre-made in design view

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        constraintLayout01.addView(btn);

        int x = 100;
        int y = 5;
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, constraintLayout01.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, x);
        set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, constraintLayout01.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, y);
    }
}
```

The button appears within the constraint view but no matter how I change x and y nothing ever changes location. What am I doing wrong? Also how can I change the size?

Edit1:
Added a button to xml as requested:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout01"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="645dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

edit2:

logcat after adding set.clone and set.applyTo:

```
2020-03-23 10:24:56.111 10888-10888/? E/.example.test0: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-03-23 10:24:56.201 10888-10888/com.example.test02 I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2020-03-23 10:24:56.210 10888-10918/com.example.test02 E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.test02
2020-03-23 10:24:56.210 10888-10918/com.example.test02 E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2020-03-23 10:24:56.307 10888-10888/com.example.test02 W/.example.test0: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-03-23 10:24:56.308 10888-10888/com.example.test02 W/.example.test0: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-03-23 10:24:56.346 10888-10888/com.example.test02 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-03-23 10:24:56.347 10888-10888/com.example.test02 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test02, PID: 10888
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test02/com.example.test02.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: All children of ConstraintLayout must have ids to use ConstraintSet
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: All children of ConstraintLayout must have ids to use ConstraintSet
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet.clone(ConstraintSet.java:713)
        at com.example.test02.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines were missing

```
    btn.setId(View.generateViewId());
    set.clone(constraintLayout);
    set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Here is the working solution with the output.

```
public class Main_One extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_one);
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.connstraint_layout); //a constraint layout pre-made in design view
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("StackFlow");
        btn.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btn.setId(View.generateViewId());
        constraintLayout.addView(btn);
        int x = 100;
        int y = 505;
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        set.clone(constraintLayout);
        set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, x);
        set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, y);
        set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
}

    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/connstraint_layout">

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it and whenever I add either or both of the lines my app crashes?

Comment: can you share the crash log?

Comment: So is it because I didn't add  ```btn.setId(View.generateViewId());``` ?

Comment: Also do you know how to answer the second part of the question, how to change the size of the button?

Comment: Height and width

Comment: If you dont set the childview id, you will get the following crash :  All Children of constraint layout should have ids to use constraint set

Comment: you can set height and width like this. btn.setHeight(300);

Comment: I didn't know that. I'll start looking at the Logcat. I can finally proceed with my project. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this line:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
```

You should get your button directly from the XML.
For example: if in the XML file, your button is named btn1.
Then, use this:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewbyId(R.id.btn1);
```

Then, try performing the operations.
It should work.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. It didn't crash but still hasn't moved.

Comment: Can you share the XML file of the layout ?

Comment: Ehh I tried it with what @Usman Zafer said so I made a button on screen and then added set.clone and set.applyTo, I managed to move the y axis, but the x axis is still not changing?

Comment: Also, please share your XML file.

Comment: That is not an XML file. I want the file with the XML code

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob, is that what you wanted to see? (under edit 1)

Comment: Yes. Try to constrain the button from all the sides. That is top, bottom, left and right.