# (Android Java) How to change dp position and size of button programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So thanks the SO community ([How to move a view (button) programmatically in a constraint layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60782881/how-to-move-a-view-button-programmatically-in-a-constraint-layout)) I know how to create and move a button programmatically, as well as change it's width and height. But I encountered some problems:

1) For some reason I can't change the button to be smaller than a certain amount (both height and width) even though no such restrictions exist when creating a button manually. How can I fix this?

2) The location I input programmatically seems to use different units than the manual one. I'm not certain if it's a pixel count or not. Can I move the button based on DP?

Here is the code I'm using, I tried making 2 buttons, one programmatically and one manually so that they both match the same size and location and overlap, but they do not.

Main:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.connstraint_layout); //a constraint layout pre-made in design view
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setHeight(40);
        btn.setWidth(40);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btn.setId(View.generateViewId());
        constraintLayout.addView(btn);
        int x = 25;
        int y = 25;
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
            set.clone(constraintLayout);
            set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, x);
            set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, y);
            set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
    }

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/connstraint_layout"
        android:layout_width="272dp"
        android:layout_height="410dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: use `valueInPixels = (valueInDp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density)`

Comment: made a function to change it: 
`public int DPtoPixels(int DP) {
        return DP * (int)Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
 }`
Doesn't quite work, the position is very different when I put it far away.

Comment: Also the height and width of the button still cannot be reduced below a certain amount.

Comment: Never mind I put the (int) in the wrong place, thanks it works! Well the position at least, still can't change the button to the correct size.

Comment: nvm, I found an answer for that:

`ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams btn_params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
        btn.setLayoutParams(btn_params);`